# PHP Webservice using nuSoap and mySQL

Tags: php, webservice-client, nusoap

I'm currently developing a PHP webservice that will be consumed by the Document Management Software *DocuWare*.
Right now it mostly consists of *reading* the database and getting a value by their ID.
The folder for the webservice consists of the following folders:

> dataLayer
>
> ServiceLayer
>
> frontEndLayer
>
> lib (nusoap)
>
> samples (nusoap)

In `dataLayer` I have `client.php`

```
<?php
    require "../lib/nusoap.php";
        $url="http://localhost/service/dataLayer/service.php";
        $client=new nusoap_client($url."?wsdl",'wsdl');
        $code=$_POST[idCourse];
        $courses=$client->call('listCourses',array("code"=>$code),'uri:'.$url,'uri:'.$url.'/listCourses');
        if($client->fault){
        echo "Error";
        print_r($courses);
        }else{
            if($client->getError()){
                echo '<b>Error: '.$client->getError().'</b>';
            }else{
                print_r($courses);
            }
        }
?>
```

and `connection.php`

```
<?php
    require(../dataLayer/auth.php);
    function connect(){
        $conn = mysql_connect($host,$hostuser,$hostpw)or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("tickets",$conn);
        return($conn);
    }
?>
```

With that in mind; I made the serviceLayer which consists of a simple `"service.php"` file.

```
<?php
    include('../lib/nusoap.php');
    require ('../dataLayer/connection.php');
    $url = "http://localhost/service/dataLayer/service.php";
    $server->configureWSDL("consult",$url);
    $server->wsdl->schematargetNamespace=$url;
    $server->soap_defencoding='utf-8';
    $server->register;
             ("listcourses",
             array("code"=> "xsd:string"),
             array("return => "xsd:string"), $url
             );

    function listcourses($code){
        $conn=connect();
        if($code!=0){
            $sql="select id from ticket where id='$code'";
        }else{
            $sql="select id from ticket";
        }
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        $i=0;
        $chainset="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
        if($rs!=null){
            $chainset.="<courses>";
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)){
                    $chainset.="<course>";
                    $chainset.="<br>";
                    $chainset.="<code>".row[0]."<code>";
                    $chainset.="<br>";
                    $chainset.="<name>".row[1]."<name>";
                    $chainset.="</course";
                    $i++;
                }
            }else{
                $chainset.="<error>No data available</error>"
            }
            $chainset.="</course";
        }else{
            $chainset.="<error>Error".mysql_error()."</error>";
        }
        $repl=new soapval('return','xsd:string',$chainset);
        return $repl;
    }
    if(!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA))
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA=file_get_contents('php://input');
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

Theorically everything is *OK*. I made the front end layer, which is just a simple form.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script src="jquery/jquery2.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            function sendForm(form){
                document.getElementById(form).submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <section id="content">
                <form id="login" name="login" method="POST" action="../dataLayer/client.php">
                    <div>
                        <label for="idCourse">Course</label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="2" id="idCourse" name="idCourse" placeholder="Example - 76" required="required" size="10"/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="reset" name="button" value="Reset"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I get the following error:

> ( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant idCourse- assumed 'idCourse' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\service\dataLayer\client.php on line 5 Call Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0003  245144  {main}( )   ...\client.php:0 Error: wsdl error: XML error parsing WSDL from
>
> http://localhost/service/dataLayer/service.php?wsdl on line 2:
>
> Invalid document end

I don't know what's wrong since everything seems to be fine.

Comment: `$code=$_POST[idCourse];` should be `$code=$_POST['idCourse'];` in client.php - this is simply a typo error. You're passing in NULL which is effecting everything else.

Comment: Thanks. That worked, however I had already moved to PDO to avoid SQL Injection, and with PDO it worked flawlessly.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: No further questions with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by [Jaquarh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5897602/jaquarh), made the following correction:

In client.php:

```
$code=$_POST['idCourse'];
```